# Loop an array of array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

in PHP, how can i loop an array of array without know if is or not an array?

Better with an example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => big
            [1] => small
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => big
            [1] => tiny
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
            [4] => e
            [5] => f
        )
    [3] => row
    [4] => cols
    [5] => blablabla
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd
            [1] => qwe
        )
}
```

any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`is_array`](http://php.net/is_array) to check if something is an array, and/or you can use [`is_object`](http://php.net/is_object) to check if it can be used within `foreach`:

```
foreach ($arr as $val)
{
    if (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) 
    {
        foreach ($val as $subval)
        {
            echo $subval;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to use a [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
           new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr),
           RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($it as $value)
{
   # ... (each value)
}
```

The recursive iterator works for multiple levels in depth.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) to check if that element is an array, if it is, loop over it recursively.

Answer (score 4):

Which approach to choose depends on what you want to do with the data.

[`array_walk_recursive` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) lets you traverse an array of arrays recursively.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $array as $value ) {
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $innerValue ) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

That would work if you know it will be a maximum of 2 levels of nested array. If you don't know how many levels of nesting then you will need to use recursion. Or you can use a function such as [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$big_array = array(...);
function loopy($array)
{
    foreach($array as $element)
    {
        if(is_array($element))
        {
            // Keep looping -- IS AN ARRAY--
            loopy($element);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something for this element --NOT AN ARRAY--
        }
    }
}

loopy();
```