# traversing an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop an array of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055123/loop-an-array-of-array)

So I know how to traverse an array of even key => value (associative), but I have a weird array where I need to walk through it and print out values:

```
$object_array = array(
    'type' => 'I am type',
    array(
        'property' => 'value',
        'property_2' => 'value_2'
    )
);
```

What I thought I could do is:

```
foreach($object as $key=>$vlaue){
   //what now?
}
```

So as you can see I am lost, how do I walk through the next array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($object as $key=>$value){
    if( is_array($value) ) {
        foreach($value as $key2=>$value2) {
            //stuff happens
        }
    } else {
        //other stuff
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try:

```
function traverse($array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
         traverse($array);
         continue;
      }
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($object_array as $value) {
  if(!is_array($value))
   echo $value;
   else {
    foreach($value as $m)
    echo $m; 
  }
 }
```

[Manual for foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you could do:

```
if(is_array($object[$key]))
    //process inner array here
```

It depends on how deep your arrays go, if you have arrays of arrays of arrays...and so on, a different method would be better, but if you just have one level this is a pretty simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
foreach($object_array as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_array($value) {
        foreach($value as $k=>$v) {
            echo $k." - ".$v;
        }
    } else {
        echo $key." - ".$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
function mydebug($value, $key) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}

array_walk_recursive($object_array, 'mydebug');
```

Handy if you doing something simple with the values (e.g. just `echo` ing).