# PHP - Merge arrays if same length into associative

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to dynamically merge multiple arrays. Consider below three different array inputs:

```
{
    "container_id": [
    {
      "key_0": "NYKU3922051"
    },
    {
      "key_0": "LACU3922051"
    }
    ],
  "out_ref": [
    {
      "key_0": "CI84621"
    },
    {
      "key_0": "DI1000"
    }
  ],
  "in_ref2": [
    {
      "key_0": "555-1106260-024"
    },
    {
      "key_0": "898-1106260-024"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to dynamically merge above three arrays `container_id`, `out_ref` and `in_ref2` into one associative one like this:

```
  {
     "array_one": {
         "key_0": "NYKU3922051",
         "key_0": "CI84621",
         "key_0": "555-1106260-024"
     },
     "array_two": {
         "key_0": "LACU3922051",
         "key_0": "DI1000",
         "key_0": "898-1106260-024"        
     }
  }
```

So what we have above, is that the first item of each array, is merged into a new array.

I am not quite sure where to start, as I can' really wrap my head around this one.

This is my PHP:

```
  $arrays = $request->all();

  $newArray = [];
  foreach ($arrays as $key => $value) {
       //???
  }
```

**EDIT**
The new array doesn't necessarily need to use the same key if this is not possible.

Comment: @Yoshi - OK they don't necessarily need to use the key `key_0`. It can just as well be: `key_0`, `key_1`, `key_2`

Comment: Key can't be duplicate, only value can be

Comment: @oliverbj So you'd be okay with a numerically-indexed array instead of an associative array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to skip the "key_0" and get a result like:

```
array(2) {
  ["array_one"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "NYKU3922051"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "CI84621"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "555-1106260-024"
  }
  ["array_two"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "LACU3922051"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "DI1000"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "898-1106260-024"
  }
}
```

By using this code that loops and seperates the values to the two arrays.

```
$arr = json_decode($str,true);

foreach($arr as $sub){
    $new["array_one"][] = $sub[0]["key_0"];
    $new["array_two"][] = $sub[1]["key_0"];
}

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/QKq4H

---

Dynamic version that can handle any amount of subarrays.
I added a counter that counts up and keeps track which array to place the value in.

```
$i = 1;
foreach($arr as $sub){
    foreach($sub as $val){
        $new["array_" . $i][] = $val["key_0"];
        $i++;
    }
    $i = 1;
}

var_dump($new);
```

Results in:

```
array(3) {
  ["array_1"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "NYKU3922051"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "CI84621"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "555-1106260-024"
  }
  ["array_2"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "LACU3922051"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "DI1000"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "898-1106260-024"
  }
  ["array_3"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "something"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "else"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "here"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/OkcXT

Comment: But what if there is “array_three” and four? In this example there is two arrays because each of the arrays gave two values. But if they have three or four values then I would need to dynamically add more arrays

Comment: @oliverbj I added a dynamic version

Comment: thanks! The dynamic version is perfect - it solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$arrays = $request->all();
$result = [];
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key_index => $keyObject) {
        if(!isset($result['array'.$key_index])) {
            $result['array'.$key_index] = ['key_0' => $keyObject['key_0']];
        } else {
            $result['array'.$key_index]['key_'.count($result['array'.$key_index])] = $keyObject['key_0'];
        }
    }
}
```

the part `$keyObject['key_0']` can be changed to be more dynamic. a way to get the value inside that associative array with only one element.

you will get something like

```
array(2) {
  ["array0"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key_0"]=>
    string(11) "NYKU3922051"
    ["key_1"]=>
    string(7) "CI84621"
    ["key_2"]=>
    string(15) "555-1106260-024"
  }
  ["array1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key_0"]=>
    string(11) "LACU3922051"
    ["key_1"]=>
    string(6) "DI1000"
    ["key_2"]=>
    string(15) "898-1106260-024"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/vpqrI

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you construct array like this, this is the link helpful for you for array traversing [traversing an array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406802/traversing-an-array-in-php) and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm

```
{
     "array_one": {
             "key_0": {
                    0 : "NYKU3922051",
                    1 : "CI84621",
                    2 : "555-1106260-024"
              }
     },
     "array_two": {
             "key_0": {
                 0 : "LACU3922051",
                 1 : "DI1000",
                 2 : "898-1106260-024"        
            }
  }
```

Comment: I don’t control the input arrays.

Comment: Really not sure if this is an answer?

Comment: @oliverbj  your expected output is not possible in this case as in PHP array keys must be unique

Comment: As said, I don’t care if the keys have dynamic names like “key_0”, “key_1” etc.

Comment: @oliverbj then why do you need keys  in associative array, simply ignore them and use numeric array to avoid value overwrite

Comment: If that is possible, then no problem! Just not sure how to do it

Comment: @oliverbj FYI, I asked you over 20 minutes ago if you'd be okay with that.

Comment: @PatrickQ So sorry! Didn’t see your question. It is totally OK