# iterate over an entire array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop an array of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055123/loop-an-array-of-array)

i was wondering if its possible to iterate over an entire array showing each of the results like this

array:

```
 $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red", "c"=> array("grey",
 "black", "yellow", "red" => "something"));
```

and then have te results like this:

green
red
green
blue
red
grey
black
yellow
something

you could say im looking to show the final value of each array if it happend not to be an array of values itself.

Comment: http://php.net/foreach http://php.net/implode

Comment: Duplicate of [Loop an array of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055123/loop-an-array-of-array) and [traversing an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406802/traversing-an-array-in-php/13406900#13406900)

Comment: [array_walk_recursive()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)?

Comment: use `echo implode(" " ,iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($input))));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would to do an `array_walk_recursive` like so:

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red", "c"=> array("grey", "black", "yellow", "red" => "something"));

array_walk_recursive($input, function($value){
    echo $value . " ";
});
```

Which then outputs:
`green red green blue red grey black yellow something`

This is php 5.4 I believe, older versions of php you need to have the function name as a string and use then create the function

Older PHP versions:

```
function myfunction($value){
    echo $value . " ";
}
array_walk_recursive($input, 'myfunction');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function to iterate all values.

```
function outputValues($arr) {
  foreach (array_values($arr) as $value) {
    if (is_array($value))
        outputValues($value);
    else
        echo $value;
  }
}
```

And use it like `outputValues($input)`.

Comment: You would benefit by looking at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8055201/164998) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8055154/164998).

Comment: let people be :) but thanks anyway for your links

Answer (score 0):

Do a foreach and check for array.

```
<?php

$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red", "c"=> array("grey",
 "black", "yellow", "red" => "something"));

foreach( $input as $value )
{
    if( is_array( $value ) )
    {
        foreach( $value as $subvalue )
        {
            echo $subvalue . ' ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo $value . ' ';
    }
} 

?>
```

PS: This could be done a much better using recursive function, but I'm too lazy to write one for you ;)

Comment: You would benefit by looking at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8055201/164998) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8055154/164998).

Answer (score 0):

```
function p($array) {
    if( !is_array( $array)) {
        echo $array . ' ';
    }else{
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if(!is_array($v)){
                echo $v . ' ';
            }else{
                p($v)
            }
        }
    }
}

p($array);
```

Comment: You would benefit by looking at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8055201/164998) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8055154/164998).